# How to filter search result with list names?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I have 3 different custom lists in my SharePoint online.
Then i made the lists into templates as the lists have to be reused for different events.

Now I made a search result to be able to find theese lists as they get created.

Is there a search querry i can use to filter theese lists by their template names?

Comment: Not template names, but you can find list by it´s template ID.

Comment: And how can i find the template id?

Answer (score 0):

Use Content Types it is much easier. Then you can query on ContentType:MyCustomContentType and find the items no matter where they reside.